# How to transfer cumulative sum to values in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, cumulative-sum

I have row with cumulative sum (A1:E1) i.e. 100;300;400;400;500 and need create row (A2:E2) with values:100;200;100;0;100
How to do it with formula in google sheets?

my try is:

```
=arrayformula(ADDRESS(row(A2:E2);COLUMN(A2:E2)))
```

but when i put

```
=indirect(arrayformula(ADDRESS(row(A2:E2);COLUMN(A2:E2)))))
```

it doesn't work so i can't use:

```
=indirect(arrayformula(ADDRESS(row(A2:E2);COLUMN(A2:E2)))))-indirect(arrayformula(ADDRESS(row(A2:E2);COLUMN(A2:E2)-1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can try:

```cpp
=REDUCE(TOROW(,1),A1:E1,LAMBDA(a,c,HSTACK(a,c-SUM(a))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After walk i found easy one:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:E1-B1:F1)
```

or without N/A and div0:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(A1:1);-(A1:1-B1:1);""))
```

Of course your solution also works. Thank you.